# Mobile version: More accessible secondary navigation?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-design, mobile, accessibility

I just discovered that the meta/main link on the mobile site is hiding down in the footer. This is very far away from everything, for someone who is used to looking for them in the top bar of the desktop site.

Can we get that footer's contents duplicated in (or moved into) the dropdown menu? Given they're static it shouldn't be any additional JS or server-side weight, and they might as well not exist for mobile users if it's taken *me* this long to find them, with how much I use the mobile site.

Comment: Agree; the footer is near impossible to get to on most of the SE super long pages.

Comment: @mxyzplk I wouldn't say impossible myself, but "tedious" does spring to mind. Certainly not discoverable or convenient.